# Write Parent's > iFrame's > iFrame Content

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have Html Layout Similar to this :

**Parent Page > iFrame**

I want to write dynamic iframe & content so the layout should look similar to this :

**Parent > iFrame > Write New iFrame & It's Content**

I'm able to write html content for child iframe using this code

**Parent Page > iFrame > Hello World!**

```
var ifrm = document.getElementById('myIframe');
ifrm = (ifrm.contentWindow) ? ifrm.contentWindow : (ifrm.contentDocument.document) ? ifrm.contentDocument.document : ifrm.contentDocument;
ifrm.document.open();
ifrm.document.write('Hello World!');
ifrm.document.close();
```

but How can I write same content inside :

**Parent Page > iFrame > iFrame > Hello World ?**

All iFrames are on same Domain.

Comment: You tagged with jQuery. WHERE'S JQUERY?

Comment: ifrm.document.write('<iframe src="somepath.html" id="my_inner_iframe"></iframe>'); and then fetch it and document write into it

Comment: @galchen I want write dynamic iframe with content so src attribute will not work that way.

Comment: then put <iframe src='about:blank'></iframe>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var ifrm = document.getElementById('myIframe');
ifrm = (ifrm.contentWindow) ? ifrm.contentWindow : (ifrm.contentDocument.document) ? ifrm.contentDocument.document : ifrm.contentDocument;
var childfrm = ifrm.document.createElement('iframe');
childfrm.id = 'myChildIframe'; // repeat for any other properties you need
ifrm.document.body.appendChild(childfrm); // or use insertBefore to add it somewhere specific within the DOM
var childwin = (childfrm.contentWindow) ? childfrm.contentWindow : (childfrm.contentDocument.document) ? childfrm.contentDocument.document : childfrm.contentDocument;
childwin.document.open();
childwin.document.write('Hello World!');
childwin.document.close();
```

(This is untested, but I think it'll work)