# How to avoid an iframe without src to read it's parent HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an `iframe` without `src` attribute. I set it's HTML from JavaScript side.

The problem is that if I load a script that contains `$("body").html()` it returns the `body`'s html of the parent document while I am expecting to get the iframe's body html.

How can I avoid such a behaviour?

I set the `iframe` HTML using:

```
$(".myResult").contents().find("html").html(myHtmlToLoad);
```

Here is a [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/QQp58/) where I reproduced the issue. I am expecting the textarea value to return calling `$(body).html()` (inside of the iframe), but it returns the HTML of the entire page (that contains the iframe).

Comment: any specific reason it has to be an iframe? It seems like there should be better alternatives if you are explicitly controlling the contents.

Comment: @Tim I would like to be a separate document.

Comment: Is this for user generated content, then, or something along those lines?

Comment: @Tim Yes, basically the user writes in a textarea his HTML and that HTML is loaded in iframe. But I see that it fails for such a call...

Comment: Ok, well even if you get it to work the way you want, there is a security issue. As far as I know, this won't protect you against cross site scripting vulnerabilities because it doesn't violate the same origin policy. If the content is saved and is visible to users other than the current one, they could sniff cookies for example.

Comment: @Tim That's true, but I don't care about that. It's a stupid little application that doesn't use cookies or something like that...

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to make sure you were aware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var ifrm = $(".result:first")[0]; 
ifrm.contentDocument.body.textContent = ""; 
var htmlDocumentStr = $(".html").val(); 
ifrm.contentDocument.write(htmlDocumentStr);
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your question, you want to get the html of the iframe. Were you looking for this?

```
var $iframe = $(".myResult");
console.log($('body', $iframe.contents());
```

You can also get a reference to the iframe's DOM with `myIframe.contentDocument`

Comment: No, I want to get the iframe body's HTML but from iframe.

Comment: The iframe loads a HTML code (that can contain `<script>` tag). When calling `$("body").html()` inside of a script tag from the loaded HTML from iframe, I want to get the iframe body's HTML. The issue is that it returns the body's html of the parent (the main document). Is this clearer now?

Comment: But don't forget that the loaded HTML is dynamic (changed by the user), so when the user will write `$("body").html()` he wants to get the iframe's html of body.

Answer (score 0):

By using `html(myHtmlToLoad)`, you are not writing into the iframe document; you are appending child elements to the  element, but are still on the parent.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14030649/100342) on how to access the iframes document.

Comment: I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null`

Answer (score 0):

Seems the main problem here is the thing that you are using jQuery from the parent page and this one is an **object** and not a class, which is assigned to the current page and uses only its body.

Since you are in the iframe, jQuery is still assigned to the parent document.

Your solution should be to especially load jQuery to an "iframe", probably with .noConflict() mode and use it inside of an iframe's JavaScript.

E.g.:

```
<script ...> // attach new jQuery to iframe

var $$ = jQuery.noConflict(); // make new object for iframe

$$("body")... // use
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing: http://jsbin.com/ASUWulO/1/edit, but it still is using the parent context.